# How to configure SAPRFC with PHP

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, sap

I am trying to configuring SAPRFC with PHP but it's fail, I tried from many ways and also referred too many links using google search but not found solution on the same,
So if anyone have configured the same, please let us know the how to configure this

I am using following Option for compilation

```
./configure --with-saprfc --enable-so
```

**Issue**

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘RFC_UNICODE’
make: *** [ext/saprfc/saprfc.lo] Error 1
```

**Specs** 
 CentOS 6.4 64 bit

I have referred [this](http://abakalidis.blogspot.in/2009/12/how-to-set-up-saprfc-extension-for-php.html) page for configuring

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.4.x you have to change the code in file saprfc.c on line 47. Change function_entry to zend_function_entry.

Credits to:
http://rotyyu.blogspot.com/2012/03/install-modul-sap-rfc-141-untuk-php-540.html